# How to determine when copy finishes in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, copy, filesystems

Does anyone know of a method to determine when a file copy completes in VBScript?  I'm using the following to copy:

```
set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
set zip = sa.NameSpace(saveFile)  
set Fol = sa.NameSpace(folderToZip)  
zip.copyHere (Fol.items)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Do Until zip.Items.Count = Fol.Items.Count
    WScript.Sleep 300
Loop
```

When the loop finishes your copy is finished.

But if you only want to copy and not zip, FSO or WMI is better.

If you are zipping and want them in a file you have to create the zip-file yourself, with the right header first. Else you only get compressed files/folders IIRC. Something like this:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile( saveFile, 2, True )
File.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String( 18, Chr(0) )
File.Close
Set File = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

The 2 in OpenTextFile is ForWriting.

Comment: potentially could be zipping, hence not using FSO

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck using the Copy method on a [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a(VS.85).aspx).  I've used it for copying, and it's a blocking call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSource = " " ' Source folder path of log files
strTarget = " .zip" ' backup path where file will be created

AddFilesToZip strSource,strTarget

Function AddFilesToZip (strSource,strTarget)
Set r=fso.GetFolder(strSource)
    set file = fso.opentextfile(strTarget,ForWriting,true) 
    file.write "PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18,chr(0)) 
    file.Close
    Set shl = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    i = 0

        For each f in r.Files
            If fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "log" Or fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "Log" Or fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "LOG" Then
            shl.namespace(strTarget).copyhere(f.Path)', FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG   
                Do until shl.namespace(strTarget).items.count = i
                    wscript.sleep 300
                Loop
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next

        set shl = Nothing
End Function
```